# Python 3 method to flip arguments in an addition operation

Tags: python-3.x, addition, reverse, datamodel

I have a class that adds two points (one of which is of type Point, and the other is a tuple or list -- see code). My problem is that my **add** method will only work if I input the numbers in a certain order. I need to create a second method (per the rules in this assignment) that only contains one line calling the **add** method and returns the result and can supposedly be found in the data model of the documentation.

```
class Point():
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __str__(self):
    return ("X = " + str(self.x) + "\nY = " + str(self.y))

def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other,list) or isinstance(other,tuple):
        newX = other[0] + self.x
        newY = other[1] + self.y
        return(Point(newX,newY))
    else:
        newX = self.x + other
        newY = self.y + other
        return(Point(newX,newY))

p = Point(5,10)
print(p + [3.5,6])
print([3.5,6] + p)
```

I've scoured the data model and I can only think that **reversed** or something with **getattr** would work, but I have no idea how to implement either, or if I'm even on the right track. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `__radd__()` in your class:

```
def __radd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.__add__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will actually do an `__add__()` as in this case it really is the same.

but you may consider making the class behave like a list, something like this:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._list = [self.x, self.y]

    def __str__(self):
        return ("X = " + str(self.x) + "\nY = " + str(self.y))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._list)

    def __iter__(self):
        for elem in self._list:
            yield elem

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._list(i)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def __delitem__(self, i):
        #not sure if you really want this
        del self._list[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        #not sure if you really want this
        self._list[i] = val    

    def __add__(self, other):
        #this code could be optimized
        #using your original code for this example
        if isinstance(other,list) or isinstance(other,tuple):
            newX = other[0] + self.x
            newY = other[1] + self.y
        else:
            newX = self.x + other
            newY = self.y + other
        #returning a list
        return [newX, newY]

    def __radd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__add__(*args, **kwargs)


p = Point(5,10)
print(p)
print(p + [3.5,6])
print([3.5,6] + p)
```

output:

```
[5, 10]
[8.5, 16]
[8.5, 16]
```

[edit] If you do decide to make it behave like a `list`, you might as well subclass `list`, example:

```
class Point(list):

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        super(Point, self).__init__([x, y])

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)):
            return [sum(i) for i in zip(self, other)]
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return [i + other for i in self]
        else:
            return self

    def __radd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__add__(*args, **kwargs)

    #you probably want a __sub__
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)):
            return [i - j for i, j in zip(self, other)]
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return [i - other for i in self]
        else:
            return self

    #and an __rsub__
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)):
            return [i - j for i, j in zip(other, self)]
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return [other - i for i in self]
        else:
            return self   

    #take away functions you do not want
    def pop(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def sort(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def append(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def extend(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def insert(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def remove(*args, **kwargs): pass
    def reverse(*args, **kwargs): pass

p = Point(5,10)
tests = [[3.5, 6], (5,4), 1.1, 'wrong string', [1, 2, 3]]
for test in tests:
    print(p + test)
    print(test + p)
for test in tests:
    print(p - test)
    print(test - p)   
p.append(4)
print(p)
```

output:

```
[8.5, 16]
[8.5, 16]
[10, 14]
[10, 14]
[6.1, 11.1]
[6.1, 11.1]
[5, 10]
[5, 10]
[6, 12]
[6, 12]
[1.5, 4]
[-1.5, -4]
[0, 6]
[0, -6]
[3.9, 8.9]
[-3.9, -8.9]
[5, 10]
[5, 10]
[4, 8]
[-4, -8]
[5, 10]
```

Comment: I obviously didn't read the documentation well enough. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @vandy, I updated the answer with an example to subclass list, which makes the code much more manageable